# Trying to hook Notepad.exe

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I'm trying to keyboard-hook Notepad.exe by using SetWindowsHookEx.

As you see, the working thread is sending its ASCII code, which is wParam, to the designated server.

```
UINT WINAPI SendToServer(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    CSocket Client;

    Client.Create();

    Client.Connect("localhost", 6677);
    Client.Send(lpParam, 2); // sending its ASICI code to Server

    Client.Close();

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH] = {0,};
    TCHAR* p = nullptr;

    if( nCode >= 0 )
    {
        // bit 31 : 0 => press, 1 => release

        if( !(lParam & 0x80000000) )
        {
            GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH);
            p = strrchr(szPath, '\\');

            if( !_stricmp(p + 1, "Notepad.exe") )
            {
                unsigned ThreadID;
                g_hThread = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, SendToServer, &wParam, 0, &ThreadID)); // a new working thread

                return 0; 
            }
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The problem is, for some reason related to the new working thread, Notepad occurs a critical error(if I click the 'ignore' button several times, it kinda works though.)

I deleted this line below,

```
g_hThread = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, SendToServer, &wParam, 0, &ThreadID)); // a new working thread
```

Then no error occurs from Notepad.exe

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is C#? It looks an awful lot like C++ to me.

Comment: Sorry it's C++. didn't add C# tag. don't know why C# tag is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for you..? Hard coded paths are used only for test purposes
change the path to match where your NotePad.exe resides

```
LRESULT  __declspec(dllexport)__stdcall CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  ofstream fout;
  fout.open("c:\\NotePad.exe",ios::app);

    if (nCode < 0 || nCode != HC_ACTION)
   return CallNextHookEx(hkb, nCode, wParam, lParam);


    if ( (((DWORD)lParam & 0x80000000) == 0) && (HC_ACTION == nCode))
  {
    if ((wParam==VK_SPACE)||(wParam==VK_RETURN)||((wParam>=0x2f ) &&(wParam<=0x100)))
        {
      if(GetAsyncKeyState(wParam) == -32767) //this solve it i got it on google but how ??
            {
        BYTE ks[256];
        GetKeyboardState(ks);

        WORD w;
        UINT scan=0;
        ToAscii(wParam,scan,ks,&w,0);
        fout<<char(w);
            }
        }
    }

     fout.close();

  return CallNextHookEx(hkb, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Hrm, no, don't "change the path to match where your notepad.exe resides". You should never hardcode paths in your application like this. If you're going to post sample code that does it for testing purposes, you need a giant warning sign with flashing red lights that says never to do it in actual code.

Comment: funny thing is .. I coded in Delphi for 17 years so I am use to the WinApi ShellExecute so the code was easy to read.. I can read C++ but prefer C#.. Happy New Year and I am glad that this works for you..

Comment: I agree Cody.. so if you can .. try to replace that hard coded path with a variable that you can either assign via a config or .INI or some other mechanism.